# Asymmetric speed on Realtek GBe

Tags: lan, gigabit-ethernet

I've got an onboard GBe card connected to a Cisco switch which is pulling down data at gigabit speed but can only push upstream at Fast Ethernet wire speed.

I've run two different tests on the PC

- Uploading to a GBe NAS
- http://speedtest.net

Both confirm that upload is limited to 100TX wire speed.

But download is limited by my bandwidth on my RAID/ISP respectively.

I've repeated the same test on my main PC with no bottleneck on the upload.

The PC is connected using a cat5 I crimped myself. I've replaced this cable repeatedly, to no effect.

The PC in question is running the latest build of Win10 main line, and uses a AMD 8350 FX.

I'm trying to figure out why the upload seems to be limited to 100mb/s.

Answer (score 0):

In windows if you go to where your network interfaces are at, and right click the one you have problems with and select properties. In that window that appears, there is a button near the top that says configure. Select the advanced tab, in that tab you can configure things that the network interface driver allows you to configure, select the Speed & duplex. Usual default is auto negotiation on the right side and has a drop down menu box. Just select that and set it to 1.0 Gbps Full duplex.

If this doesn't fix your problem, then either you need to update your driver or the driver is faulty. If that is not the case, then its your switch or something beyond that that is limiting it.

Comment: I've switched it from auto negotiate to 1GBe with no result. Not the issue. Sorry.

Comment: try checking to see if your nic has updated drivers available as well, not sure if you have done this yet or not as you didn't specify.

Comment: Also, another possibly is background applications doing some kind of network communication, like windows updates. If you left the updates on default settings, you are allowing the internet to download some windows updates from you.

Comment: its very unlikely. A. it's a fresh install from msdn. B. It's almost exactly 100TX wire speed. C. It's UPSTREAM that is slow. Downstream is perfect.

Comment: What is the nic card you have? I know its onboard, but it should still have some kind of way of identifing the integrated nic.

Comment: Realtek GBe PCIe. Hard to identify because Gigabyte technology don't give more details than that...

Comment: I have ran out of ideas of what is causing this, except that its possible that if the switch is configurable. It is possible the switch is limiting your connection.

Comment: Swapped that out and also it's a friggin Cisco switch...